# 20th century kids' fantasy novel with a castle on the cover

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

During the early 1960s, I noticed, but never read, a children's fantasy novel in the children's room of the Abington Library in Jenkintown, PA.

I think that it was a fantasy novel because the description inside the cover mentioned fairies or elves.

Anyway, I remember that the cover or dust jacket had an image of a sort of a fairy tale castle based or a medieval French chateau with white walls and blue roofs.

The castle might have been as tall and vertical as a Disney theme park castle.

https://www.wdw-magazine.com/disney-castles-around-the-world-the-history-inspiration-and-whats-inside-them/

But if I remember correctly it was much more symmetrical looking.

So it would have looked more like the Chateau of Pierrefonds as restored by Violet-le-Duc in the 19th century.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C3%A2teau_de_Pierrefonds#/media/File:Ch%C3%A2teau_de_Pierrefonds_vu_depuis_le_Parc.jpg

Or like the Louvre in the late late Middle ages.

http://historic-cities.huji.ac.il/france/paris/stroll/louvre/louvre.html

https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/medieval-louvre-3d-model/974358

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Louvre_-_Les_Tr%C3%A8s_Riches_Heures.jpg

So I hope that someone will remember a book with a cover depicting such a castle.

Comment: Do you remember any other elements in the cover? Even pre-1965, there were a LOT of fantasy novels with castles on their cover.